# Windows 11 won't boot normally after hibernating

Tags: windows, boot, windows-11, hibernate, duplex

After hibernating, I wake my Asus FA507RC up, but something strange: The Asus logo appear on the screen, and the spinner start spinning one second, then the screen black, then the logo and spinner appear again and after spinning 5-7 seconds, I can go to my desktop but nothing remained. I open Firefox and it said something like "the browser did not stop correctly, restore last session?".

If I restart (not hibernate), the spinner and logo appeared once

I think there was an error occurred at the first spinner, so it cannot boot from hibernating, then the second spinner is when it try to restart.

PS: some previous days it worked but after upgrading hardware and software  (8 + 16 ddr5 4800hz, installed avast antivirus, wsl2, update windows security patches) it did not work.

Also tried to troubleshoot, reset powercfg, turn off fast startup, ... but no luck. Please help

Comment: You could perhaps try to undo the software changes/patches in stages. Windows Update is the best candidate for causing problems.